# Difference between `!== undefined` and `in`

Tags: javascript, object

Why would one use `in` over `!== undefined` to check if an object contains a key?
For example:

```
var obj = {};
obj.a !== undefined; // false
'a' in obj; // false
```

What's the difference?

Comment: Did you just ask and answer your question within the same minute?

Comment: @Loaf yes, http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Loaf That's actually encouraged, but not for trivial questions with answers that can be found all over the internet

Comment: @LieuweRooijakkers - Oh so perhaps you have an issue you are working on that you finally fixed, and you couldn't find the solution, do what you do to help other users? Got it

Comment: @Loaf indeed, I couldn't find the answer that easily so I guessed it would be worth it to share the answer I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!== undefined` checks if a value is `undefined`. `in` checks if an object contains a key, which value still can be `undefined`:

```
var obj = {
    a: undefined,
};
obj.a !== undefined; // false
'a' in obj; // true
```

Comment: @MaxZoom I think you are wrong, Arrays use indexes. Both key \ property : value pairs apply to an object Object. The naming is interchangeable.You can use them both. But, there's a slight difference between them too.

Comment: @BekimBacaj I have added a new post to show the difference

Answer (score 0):

As per official [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator **`in`** checks if specified property exists in a given object.
Below code illustrates that there is a difference between `property` and `key`:

```js
// define Point object
function Point() {
  this.xPos = 0;
  this.yPos = 0;
}

// Add new property
Object.defineProperty(Point.prototype, "position", {
   get: function() {
     return "X: " + this.xPos + " Y: " + this.yPos;
   },
   set: function(thePoint) {
     var parts = thePoint.split(", ");
     this.xPos = parts[0] || "";
     this.yPos = parts[1] || "";
   }
});

var aPoint = new Point();
aPoint.position= "10, 20";
console.log("Point coordinates " + aPoint.position);
console.log("Point has position: " + ('position' in aPoint));
console.log("Point keys: " + Object.keys(aPoint));
```